# What is the difference between a homebrew and wget install of youtube-dl?

Tags: homebrew, wget, youtube-dl

When youtube-dl is installed through homebrew on an M1 Macbook Air with these commands, the resulting instance doesn't support reddit video downloads and requires some URLs to be in quotation marks:

```
brew install youtube-dl
```

Instead, if youtube-dl is installed via these commands, the resulting instance doesn't have the same issues:

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

I'm curious to know what the difference is between these installs but haven't been able to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

*doesn't support reddit video downloads(...)doesn't have the same issue*

Reason which comes first to mind is that you installed different versions, this

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

does grab latest version from youtube-dl webpage, which is most probably where new version will appear first, whilst

```
brew install youtube-dl
```

does grab version which is present in brew repository, it depend on maintainer of `youtube-dl` for `brew`, which might update it less often.

Note that in case of `youtube-dl` it is possible to have version which once did worked correctly with certain content provider e.g. *reddit video* but it is not longer due to changes in that, say *reddit video* change way you have to access their material.

Comment: Thanks Daweo, sensible line of thinking. I might get in touch with the devs.